# Include null in MS SQL query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a SQL novice but need to update this query to include 'NULL' results for the following fields:

```
DrCity
DrST
PhoneOffice 
SmnrDate
SmnrID
```

What do I need to do in order to get 'NULL' results for these fields. Right now, the query excludes NULL results for, at minimum, SmnrDate and SmnrID.

Thank you.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report_ActiveClients_ByConsultant] 
     @EmpID varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
           EmpID
         , LastName
         , FirstName
         , DrCity
         , DrST
         , PhoneOffice
         , [Status] 
         , Seminar.SmnrName
         , CONVERT(varchar(10), Smnr.SmnrDate, 101) AS SeminarDate
    FROM                  (SELECT EmpID
                                , Contact.ContactID
                                , LastName
                                , FirstName
                                , DrCity
                                , DrST
                                , PhoneOffice
                                , [Status]
                                , MAX(SmnrDate) AS SmnrDate 
                                FROM Consultant INNER JOIN Contact ON Consultant.EmpID = Contact.Consultant1
                                                INNER JOIN ContactNameLink ON Contact.ContactID = ContactNameLink.lnkContactID
                                                INNER JOIN ContactName ON ContactNameLink.lnkNameID = ContactName.NameID 
                                                LEFT JOIN SmnrAttnDetail ON Contact.ContactID = SmnrAttnDetail.ContactID
                                                LEFT JOIN Seminar ON SmnrAttnDetail.SmnrID = Seminar.SmnrID
                                WHERE  ((@EmpID = '' AND Consultant.Active='1') OR Consultant.EmpID = @EmpID)
                                        AND Contact.Active='Yes'
                                        AND Contact.ContactType='Client'
                                        AND (Contact.[Status] = 'ACS' 
                                        OR Contact.[Status] =  'AC'
                                        OR Contact.[Status] =  'BC'
                                        OR Contact.[Status] =  'QS'
                                        OR Contact.[Status] =  'SAT'
                                        OR Contact.[Status] = 'LC'
                                        OR Contact.[Status] = 'AS')
                                        AND ContactNameLink.[Primary] = 1

                                GROUP BY EmpID, Contact.ContactID, LastName, FirstName, DrCity, DrST, PhoneOffice, [Status]) AS Smnr
                LEFT JOIN SmnrAttnDetail ON SmnrAttnDetail.ContactID = Smnr.ContactID
                INNER JOIN Seminar ON SmnrAttnDetail.SmnrID = Seminar.SmnrID AND Seminar.SmnrDate = Smnr.SmnrDate

    GROUP BY EmpID, Smnr.ContactID, LastName, FirstName, DrCity, DrST, PhoneOffice, [Status], Seminar.SmnrName, Smnr.SmnrDate
    ORDER BY EmpID, LastName

END
```

Final code:

```
SELECT     dbo.StatusCode.Code, dbo.Contact.ContactType, dbo.Contact.Active, dbo.Contact.Status, dbo.ContactName.Title, dbo.ContactName.FirstName, 
                      dbo.ContactName.LastName, dbo.Contact.Addr1, dbo.Contact.City AS DrCity, dbo.Contact.ST AS DrST, dbo.Contact.PhoneClinic AS PhoneOffice, dbo.Contact.DateJoined, 
                      dbo.Contact.Consultant1 AS EmpID, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.qyLastSmnrActiveReport.LastSmnr, 101),'None') AS SeminarDate, dbo.qyLastSmnrActiveReport.SmnrName
FROM         dbo.Contact INNER JOIN
                      dbo.StatusCode ON dbo.Contact.Status = dbo.StatusCode.Code INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ContactNameLink ON dbo.Contact.ContactID = dbo.ContactNameLink.lnkContactID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Consultant ON Contact.Consultant1 = Consultant.EmpID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ContactName ON dbo.ContactNameLink.lnkNameID = dbo.ContactName.NameID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.qyLastSmnrActiveReport ON dbo.Contact.ContactID = dbo.qyLastSmnrActiveReport.ContactID
WHERE     (dbo.Contact.Active = N'Yes') AND (dbo.Contact.Status IN (N'AC', N'QS', N'BC', N'LS', N'ACS', N'SAT', N'ACS', N'AS')) AND (dbo.Contact.ContactType = N'CLIENT') AND 
                      (dbo.ContactNameLink.[Primary] = 1) AND ((@EmpID = '' AND dbo.Consultant.Active='1') OR Consultant1 = @EmpID)
                      ORDER BY EmpID, LastName, FirstName
```

Comment: Try changing outer query's `INNER JOIN Seminar...` to an outer join: `LEFT JOIN Seminar...`

Comment: Rather than editing the question with the answer, it's a better practice on StackOverflow to add your solution as an answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You should have enough rep to do so now.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
INNER JOIN Seminar
```

with

```
LEFT JOIN Seminar
```

Comment: This causes the application calling the SQL query to crash with the following error: "The value for column 'SeminarDate' in table 'Report_ActiveClients_ByConsultant' is DBNull."  (So I see that the SQL is correct, but now this creates another issue.)

Comment: Then it's probably the `CONVERT` that don't like NULL. Try replacing `CONVERT(varchar(10), Smnr.SmnrDate, 101)`by `Smnr.SmnrDate`

Comment: Unfortunately, no go.

Comment: Error Description:The value for column 'SeminarDate' in table 'Report_ActiveClients_ByConsultant' is DBNull.

Comment: Error Description:Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Comment: I did update the report in Visual Studio to allow null for the SmnrDate field but the 'failed to enable constraints' still appeared.

Comment: I've spent 3 more hours on this so far today with no luck.  The basic issue is that anything having to do with Seminar can't be a criteria for which rows are selected. I want to display two columns from the Seminar table if there is matching data but it cannot be a factor in which rows are selected in the first place.

Comment: I don't have any more idea from your query but it is a little complex and maybe I could help you more efficiently if you provide a sample of your DB on [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I finally got it. The key was changing the SeminarDate field in the ReportDataSet in Visual Studio to (Empty) instead of "Throw Exception". Also "LEFT OUTER JOIN" instead of "LEFT JOIN".